# Shortest path to sort a list through item exchanging

Tags: operations-research

What is the shortest path to sort a list through item exchanging?
Recently, I met a math problem. I'd like to find an apporach to convert a list to ordered list by item exchanging with corresponding costs.
In short, the problem is as follows:

For a list [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5]
 I'd like to sort it into a sorted list through item exchanging. That is to say I can only exchange the position of two item at each time. But there is a cost for exchanging items. The cost is calculated by multiply the distance and the difference of this two items.
**cost = |xi -xj| * |i-j|**

For example, given a list [3,2,9,1]
Path No.1: We first exchange 3 and 9, then 3 will be in the right position, the cost of this step is |9-3| * 2 = 12. Then the list becomes [9,2,3,1], we exchange 9 and 1 with the cost |9-1| * 3 = 24. So we get an ordered list with the total cost 36.

Path No.2: First exchange 3 and 1, which gives cost = |3-1| * 3 = 6, then we get [1,2,9,3]. Next, we exchange 3 and 9 to get a order lsit, which gives the cost = |9-3| * 1 = 6. Hence, the total cost is 12.

I found that we can always get the shortest path by first exchanging the smallest item to the right position. **But my qusetion is about the reason. How to prove that this method always gives the shortest path even when the the original list goes longer**(more than 4 item)?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Solving (9,3,1,2) can be done with a cost of 21 if you solve 2 first, but costs 24 if you solve 1 or 9 first.